# "object required" error while selecting a file and displaying the path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a browse button on an excel sheet by clicking which i can select a file and the path of the selected file will get displayed in a textbox on the same excel sheet.This is the code i have tried:

```
Dim File_Path As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show

GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
TextBox1.Value = GetFolder
End With
End Sub
```

when i run the code,i am able to select a file but then i am getting a runtime error "object required" and the line

```
TextBox1.Value = GetFolder
```

is getting highlighted.can anyyone please help me with this.thank you.

Comment: Error suggest that you don't have any `TextBox object` in the Activesheet or on UserForm. Possible solution (when talking about ActiveSheet): `ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value = GetFolder`

Comment: thank you KazJaw...i do have a textbox on the sheet and i have no idea how to sort this..

Comment: see the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error suggest that you don't have any TextBox object in the Activesheet or Object reference is not complete.

Possible solution (when talking about ActiveSheet):

```
ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value = GetFolder
```

or when talking about any other sheet:

```
Sheets("NameOfTheSheetHere").TextBox1.Value = GetFolder
```

Comment: thank you KazJaw..it works perfect...can you please say me how can i have a submit button in case i have a browse button and text field for each a source file(copy),a destination file(paste) and an interface file...

Comment: to be honest I don't understand what you need. I suggest to try something and post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood the question.

Here is another way.

Replace

```
TextBox1.Value = GetFolder
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = getfolder
```

In a more structured way...

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim File_Path As Long
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox1")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        getfolder = .SelectedItems(1)

        shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = getfolder
    End With
End Sub
```

Also instead of `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` you may use the inbuilt `Application.GetOpenFilename`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")
    If Ret <> False Then _
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = getfolder
End Sub
```

BTW change `"Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*"` to `"All Files (*.*), *.*"` if you want to show all files and not just Excel Files.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply...i have to say you that the button i have used is from form controls and as the textbox is greyed in the form controls , i have put the textbox1 from the activex controls..so,may it be the reason for this error? thank you again

Comment: thank u very much for the clear reply siddharth Rout..can you please tell me how can i have a submit button  which takes the source file,destinatin file and an interface file...i tired making a submit button and linked it with a macro..but it doesnt work

Comment: what do you want to do exactly with the `source file`? And what is an Interface file?

Comment: source file has the columns that i want to copy and the interface file has the mapping of the columns(from which column in source to which column in destination)....thank you again

Comment: In that case this becomes entirely a new question and has nothing to do with the existing question. I would recommend that you post a new question for this.

Comment: I just noticed that @KazJaw also suggested the same thing to you :)

Comment: You should have accepted KazJaw's answer and not mine as he was the first to give you a correct answer :)